# If a meanwell ldh-45 led driver provides a range of voltage outputs at a constant current, how is my desired voltage selected?

Tags: led

http://www.meanwell.com/search/LDH-45/LDH-45-spec.pdf

350mA = current.

Lets say my LED forward biases at 42v.

Is it a 120 ohm resistor that I need?  42V = 0.35A*120 Ohms

I am a bit confused.  Typically when working with LEDs people call the resistor current limiting.

Answer (score 3):

It will output whatever voltage between 18 and 86 volts that it needs to get 350 mA flowing in the LEDs. You don't need any resistor. This is the point of a constant current supply, you can put any load on it and know you will get the right current.